# Shell scripting. Command substitution issue in my script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, cygwin

On both, my Cygwin and my Linux box (Debian) I'm experiencing same issue:

I'm working in a shell script with some kind of formatting ids, I want to add a backslash () before a slash occurrence (/).

My sed script is working well at my terminal:

```
# export someid="314-12345/08"
# echo "${someid}" | sed 's/\//\\\//'
```

Output:

```
314-12345\/08
```

But not as well if i run [command substitution](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/commandsub.html):

```
# someidformatted=`echo "${someid}" | sed 's/\//\\\//'`
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
```

What I'm missing here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no obligation to use / as the separator for sed.

```
s/a/c/
```

May become

```
s#a#c#
```

So in your case:

```
someidformatted=`echo "${someid}" | sed 's#\/#\\\/#'`
```

would do the job.

I can only guess that the problem was caused by some lack of / escaping.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. Is much clear to use # instead / in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what is going on.  From the bash(1) man page, emphasis mine:

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning **except when followed by  $, ‘, or \.**  The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

So most likely you need more backslashes for the command substitution than a plain command.
You can debug this by setting `set -x`:

```
# someidformatted=`echo "${someid}" | sed 's/\//\\\//'`
++ echo 314-12345/08
++ sed 's/\//\\//'
sed: 1: "s/\//\\//": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
+ someidformatted=
# someidformatted=$(echo "${someid}" | sed 's/\//\\\//')
++ echo 314-12345/08
++ sed 's/\//\\\//'
+ someidformatted='314-12345\/08'
```

So, you can see that an occurrence of `\\` gets turned to `\`.  Adding more backslashes works, but I prefer the `$(command)` form:

```
# someidformatted=$(echo "${someid}" | sed 's/\//\\\//')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. +1 for other solution that accepted one and 'set -x'.